# JS variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple js variables:

```
var check_first  = 0;
var check_second = 1;
```

Then, `<div class="chosen" data-type ='first'>`

I have a function to get the data attribute:

```
$(document).on('click', '.chosen', function (e) {
    var type = $(this).data('type');
});
```

When the `.chosen` is clicked, I get the `type` variable with the value of "`first`"

Then I want to use this value to identify one of the two variables at the top and get the value of 0:

For example:

```
var chosen = check_ + type; //of course wrong, and should give "check_first" when properly written.
console.log(chosen); //giving 0 as the result
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best chance is to use a simple key-value object to achieve this:

```
var check = {
    first: 0,
    second: 1
};

$(document).on('click', '.chosen', function (e) {
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    console.log(check[type]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try.